# I have reviews I can do, but none show up! Why?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I am constantly checking the `review` section of StackOverflow; however, nothing is really showing up in

- [First Answer Stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats)
- [Late Answer Stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats)

**I am refreshing the page, and I can see that `reviews today` are increasing**; however, nothing is showing up in the `needs review` part? What is up with that?

I have also seen that sometimes there are reviews that `need review`; however when I do go to review them, there is nothing to review!!

---

[image]

---

[image: Now there are no results]

Comment: @ProgramFOX My issue is different from that question. I am not getting an error message at all

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski The answer also applies to this question, and the last sentence of the question says: "the caching now creates some off numbers, so the displayed number became unreliable."

Comment: So there is no fix? Will there be no-cached results soon?

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski: no, they just introduced the cached version to fix the problems not caching caused.

Comment: So as it was mentioned before....that page is now actually useless. We have to check the real page for updates manually.

Comment: Actually, I am wondering. I kept on refreshing the pages for updated reviews, but nothing would ever show up... however the stat page would always show that there were reviews being done. That does NOT seem like a caching problem.

Comment: Perhaps you additionally have a tag-filter applied there?

Comment: No, I don't have any tags in. This could be due to the caching "fix"; however, it still seems strange and partially not related